# Django Rest Framework not saving foreign key for a small number of requests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to provide API to a mobile app. I have two models, Order and User. Order has a foreign key relation to User.

For about 1% or so of all my order objects, the User field is null. I've been testing this behavior using cURL.

If I do a cURL without a user object, it tells me "This field is required".
If done with a wrong user object, it tells me that the object does not exist. Both of these are the intended and expected behaviors.

I'm trying to figure out how it is possible for some of the Order objects to be saved without a user field. Is there something I'm not taking into account?

My views:

```
class OrderList (generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Order
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

And serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field = 'user')
    partial = True

    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

Models:

```
class User (models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length =200, unique=True)

class Order (models.Model):
    uid = models.ForeignKey (User, related_name = "orders", verbose_name = "User",blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you show us your model definition?

Comment: @PiotrKowalczuk editted to add the models!

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different `ModelSerializer` classes, one for creation, that makes sure, that an `Order` object can't be created without a related `User` and one for updating orders, that passes `required=False` to the related field's constructor, so that you still can save existing orders that haven't a related `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding *default=None* to your models.ForeignKey declaration. You could also just create an anonymous user in the users table and when the user isn't specified it could set the anonymous user instead.